# How to set a Content-Type when uploading a data on an Azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a simple web application that received the name of a pdf file and load this pdf on a Azure blob storage.

```
class AzureUploader(web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def _write_remotely(self):
        json_body = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
        filename = json_body.get("filename")
        container_client = ContainerClient(
            f'https://{REMOTE_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net/',
            REMOTE_CONTAINER,
            credential=REMOTE_ACCESS_KEY
        )
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)

              blob_client.set_http_headers(content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/pdf'))
        logging.info('PROPERTIES {}'.format(blob_client.get_blob_properties()))

        with open(os.path.join(json_body.get("path"), filename), "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        logging.info('UPLOAD ALL REQUEST RECEIVED')
        # Data received
        self._write_remotely()

        return
```

I need to set the Content-Type to application/pdf (the default is application/octet-stream).
Apparently I do that, because when I log all the header parameters, inside the field *content_settings* the value is *'content_type': 'application/pdf'*:

```
[I 230809 12:56:01 pdf_receipt_sender_to_azure:70] PROPERTIES {'name': '100099_20230807_1411_010_00339_0487970002881.PDF', 'container': 'invoices/documents', 'snapshot': None, 'versio
n_id': None, 'is_current_version': None, 'blob_type': <BlobType.BLOCKBLOB: 'BlockBlob'>, 'metadata': {}, 'encrypted_metadata': None, 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 9, 10, 
56, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'etag': '"0x8DB98C7389BE957"', 'size': 37463, 'content_range': None, 'append_blob_committed_block_count': None, 'is_append_blob_sealed': None, 'pa
ge_blob_sequence_number': None, 'server_encrypted': True, 'copy': {'id': None, 'source': None, 'status': None, 'progress': None, 'completion_time': None, 'status_description': None, 'i
ncremental_copy': None, 'destination_snapshot': None}, 'content_settings': {'content_type': 'application/pdf', 'content_encoding': None, 'content_language': None, 'content_md5': None, 
'content_disposition': None, 'cache_control': None}, 'lease': {'status': 'unlocked', 'state': 'available', 'duration': None}, 'blob_tier': 'Hot', 'rehydrate_priority': None, 'blob_tier
_change_time': None, 'blob_tier_inferred': True, 'deleted': False, 'deleted_time': None, 'remaining_retention_days': None, 'creation_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 7, 12, 11, 16, tz
info=datetime.timezone.utc), 'archive_status': None, 'encryption_key_sha256': None, 'encryption_scope': None, 'request_server_encrypted': True, 'object_replication_source_properties': 
[], 'object_replication_destination_policy': None, 'last_accessed_on': None, 'tag_count': None, 'tags': None, 'immutability_policy': {'expiry_time': None, 'policy_mode': None}, 'has_le
gal_hold': None, 'has_versions_only': None}
```

But then the upload is done with the following parameters:

```
[I 230809 12:56:01 _universal:523] Request URL: 'https://app.blob.core.windows.net/invoices/documents/100099_20230807_1411_010_00339_0487970002881.PDF'
    Request method: 'PUT'
    Request headers:
        'Content-Length': '37463'
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'REDACTED'
        'If-None-Match': '*'
        'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
        'Accept': 'application/xml'
        'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.14.1 Python/3.7.9 (Linux-4.15.0-74-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial)'
        'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
        'x-ms-client-request-id': '5453fcf2-36a3-11ee-ae74-00505680a149'
        'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
    A body is sent with the request
```

So the content-type is changed back to application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 0):

> How to set a Content-Type when uploading data on an Azure blob storage

You can use the below sample code to upload the pdf file with **`'content_type': 'application/pdf'`** using Azure Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings

connection_string = "your-connection-string"
container_name = "test"
blob_name = "sample.pdf"
file_path = "C:\\Users\\test890.pdf"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)

content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type='application/pdf')

with open(file_path, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data, content_settings=content_settings)
    print("The file is uploaded with content-type in your account")
```

Output:

```
The file is uploaded with content-type in your account
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

You can change your code to the below format:

**Code:**

```
class AzureUploader(web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def _write_remotely(self):
        json_body = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
        filename = json_body.get("filename")
        container_client = ContainerClient(
            f'https://{REMOTE_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net/',
            REMOTE_CONTAINER,
            credential=REMOTE_ACCESS_KEY
        )
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
        content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type='application/pdf')

            with open(os.path.join(json_body.get("path"), filename), "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data, content_settings=content_settings)

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        logging.info('UPLOAD ALL REQUEST RECEIVED')
        # Data received
        self._write_remotely()
        return
```

**Reference:**

[azure.storage.blob.ContentSettings class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.contentsettings?view=azure-python)

Comment: It doesn't work, the header logged during the request is always octet-stream. The only difference is that I have now also this header: 'x-ms-blob-content-type': 'REDACTED'

Comment: Hi, @k4ppa Have you tried my above approach? while uploading data you need to add with content-settings.

Comment: Yes I replaced my line of code with: blob_client.upload_blob(data, content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/pdf'))